# Newsletter Popup on Home Page - Bigcommerce

Tags: jquery, cookies, slider, bigcommerce

I have a Bigcommerce site and am finding the location of the newsletter signup (footer) hard for users to find. I wanted to use a sliding box (see hotsy totsy) as I'm familiar with that functionality - to make the popup appear when people first visit the home page and only make it happen once using cookies.

I couldn't find anything on Bigcommerce and the forum regarding cookies and their support is unhelpful in this regard.

Are you also able to let me know the name of the function that's being used to implement the sliding box?

Answer (score 0):

This uses fancybox.js and jquery.cookie.js to create a newsletter popup for our shop that sets a cookie to expire in two weeks

```
<!-- Newsletter HTML -->
<a id="signup" href="#newsletter-popup"></a><!-- a tag to trigger fancybox click -->
<div id="newsletter-popup"><!-- newsletter div -->
    <div id="newsletter-popup-wrap">
            <div id="newsletter-popup-content">
                    <h1>Join the Mailing List!</h1>
                    <div class="BlockContent">
                        <form>
                           <input type="email" onclick="this.value='';" value="E-mail Address">
                            <input type="submit" value="%%LNG_Submit%%" class="Button"  name="Submit">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <span>Receive exclusive offers! </span>
            </div><!-- end content -->
    </div><!-- end wrap -->
</div><!-- end newsletter div -->

<!-- Newsletter JS -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Check for recent cookie
    //if cookie, don't show popup    
    var visited = $.cookie('visited');
    if (visited == 'yes') {
        return false;
    } else {
    //show popup
        $("#signup").fancybox({'overlayShow':true,frameWidth:621,frameHeight:524,padding:2,'hideOnContentClick':false}).trigger('click');
    }
    //and set a cookie with expiration some number of days in the future
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', { expires: 14 });
});
</script>
```

The sliding box (carousel) on the home page is flexslider: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/